# This expression was expected to have type 'System.String' but here has type 'string'

Tags: f#

How is it possible that the F# compiler rejects the type `string` when it's expecting a `System.String`?

```
    #I @"..\..\packages"
    #r @"FSharp.Data\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"
    open FSharp.Data
    let [<Literal>] csvFile = @"..\..\data\FootballResults.csv"
    type Football = CsvProvider< csvFile >
    let data = Football.GetSample().Rows |> Seq.toArray
```

After running this simple code, I get the error message:

*Script.fsx(5,30): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type 'System.String' but here has type 'string'*

I thought `string` was simply an alias for `System.String`?

### Edit

The csv file is quite big, just the first rows are important:

---

Date,Home Team,Away Team,Full Time Home Goals,Full Time Away Goals,Full Time Result,Half Time Home Goals,Half Time Away Goals,Half Time Result,Home Shots,Away Shots,Home Shots on Target,Away Shots on Target,Home Fouls,Away Fouls,Home Cards,Away Cards,Home Yellow Cards,Away Yellow Cards,Home Red Cards,Away Red Cards
08/18/2012,Arsenal,Sunderland,0,0,D,0,0,D,14,3,4,2,12,8,7,0,0,0,0,0
08/18/2012,Fulham,Norwich,5,0,H,2,0,H,11,4,9,2,12,11,6,3,0,0,0,0
08/18/2012,Newcastle,Tottenham,2,1,H,0,0,D,6,12,4,6,12,8,3,5,2,2,0,0

---

The full file can be downloaded [here](https://www.manning.com/downloads/1473) under the folder data

### FSharp.Data version

FSharp.Data 2.3.2

Comment: Can we see your CSV file (or a part of it), so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: You'll also need to post the version of FSharp.Data you're using.

Comment: I've added the info in the post

Comment: After digging a bit, I've forced the type on the instanciation let [<Literal>] csvFile:System.String = @"..\..\data\FootballResults.csv". The error has changed to error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type 'System.String (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)' but here has type 'System.String (System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)'

Comment: This looks like your F# is somehow loading two different standard .NET libraries with two strings. I'm not sure why that might be happening though.

Comment: I suspect the problem here is that you have somehow mixed .NET Core with .NET Framework.

Comment: The problem was linked to the version of FSharp.Data

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, it was in the paket script provided in the book [Get Programming with F#](https://www.manning.com/books/get-programming-with-f-sharp?query=F#).
The script was pointing to an old version of FSharp.Data (I thought paket was this amazing package manager that always get you the best version for your project while in fact, it does not, you always fight and struggle with wrong dependencies).

At the end I managed to fix the problem this way:

### Solution 1

Simply start a new project using the nuget command `Install-Package FSharp.Data -Version 4.2.7` and then the reference to the package `#r "nuget: FSharp.Data"`

### Solution 2

Update the paket.lock provided by the book with the correct version FSharp.Data (4.2.7). The code posted in my question run after that.

### Advice for F# learner

Whoever is trying to learn F# with this book, it's a good book but be very careful with their package reference. They seem outdated and can get you into unpleasant situation.

Comment: Note for Paket - it's great at locking down versions of things. There's really no such thing as  a package manager that always gets you the best version for your project. But paket makes it very very hard to get something _other_ than the exact version specified.